# django-registration where to set domain and protocol variable?

Tags: django, django-registration

in my django app I am using django-registration app. I was testing registration few months ago and it worked fine. I have not editing nothin in django-registration since then, but somehow it's not working anymore. Well registration mail does not contain proper link:

```
Someone, hopefully you, signed up for a new account at domain.com using this email address. If it was you, and you'd like to activate and use your account, click the link below or copy and paste it into your web browser's address bar:

:///accounts/activate/3789be99f7426ab3e332d252900479b59a400d45/

If you didn't request this, you don't need to do anything; you won't receive any more email from us, and the account will expire automatically in seven days.
```

This is my activation_email.txt

```
{% load humanize %}
Someone, hopefully you, signed up for a new account at domain.com using this email address. If it was you, and you'd like to activate and use your account, click the link below or copy and paste it into your web browser's address bar:

{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}/accounts/activate/{{ activation_key }}/

If you didn't request this, you don't need to do anything; you won't receive any more email from us, and the account will expire automatically in {{ expiration_days|apnumber }} days.
```

So protocol and domain variable is not passed. Where should I set them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think django-registration takes information about domain from django-site table -- you should check domain field in that table or edit it through admin page.

You can read about sites framework here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/

Comment: I have my domain -> "domain.com" set in django_site table. But I have changed example.com to "domain.com" in db by sql update statement. I have "SITE_ID = 1" in my settings and id in django_site is also 1. I am using south for migration.

Comment: the template you use looks a bit similar to the password reset template, but the activation_email templates are NOT fed with the values you use. I just had a similar issue and noticed that there is no protocol (or similar) variable available, so it just works with hardcoded http or https in the template. just google for some default templates for django-registration to see a working template (not working for flexible http/https though).